# PowerShell-How to get values from this JSON file

Tags: powershell

This is the partial data after removed the confidential information.

```html
{
   "WebhookName":"Azure-CustomAlert-Webhook",
   "RequestBody":"{\"schemaId\":\"azureMonitorCommonAlertSchema\",\"data\":{\"essentials\":{\"alertId\":\"/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXX/providers/Microsoft.AlertsManagement/alerts/XXXXXXX\",\"alertRule\":\"Low Memory\",\"severity\":\"Sev3\",\"signalType\":\"Log\",\"monitorCondition\":\"Fired\",\"monitoringService\":\"Log Analytics\",\"alertTargetIDs\":[\"/subscriptions/XXXXX/resourcegroups/XXXX-RG/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/workspacename\"],\"configurationItems\":[\"USE2V5TMP9001\"],\"originAlertId\":\"XXXXX\",\"firedDateTime\":\"2022-03-09T17:49:41.4631455Z\",\"description\":\"Triggers an alert for a low memory condition\",\"essentialsVersion\":\"1.0\",\"alertContextVersion\":\"1.1\"},\"alertContext\":{\"SearchQuery\":\"Perf | where ( CounterName == \\\"% Used Memory\\\" or CounterName == \\\"% Committed Bytes In Use\\\" ) | where Computer contains (\\\"TMP\\\") | summarize AggregatedValue = avg(CounterValue) by Computer, bin(TimeGenerated, 5m)\",\"SearchIntervalStartTimeUtc\":\"2022-03-09T17:42:10Z\",\"SearchIntervalEndtimeUtc\":\"2022-03-09T17:47:10Z\",\"ResultCount\":1,\"SeverityDescription\":\"Informational\",\"WorkspaceId\":\"XXXXX\",\"SearchIntervalDurationMin\":\"5\",\"AffectedConfigurationItems\":[\"USE2V5TMP9001\"],\"AlertType\":\"Metric measurement\",\"IncludeSearchResults\":true,\"Dimensions\":[{\"Name\":\"Computer\",\"Value\":\"USE2V5TMP9001\"}],\"SearchIntervalInMinutes\":\"5\",\"SearchResults\":{\"tables\":[{\"name\":\"PrimaryResult\",\"columns\":[{\"name\":\"Computer\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"TimeGenerated\",\"type\":\"datetime\"},{\"name\":\"AggregatedValue\",\"type\":\"real\"}],\"rows\":[[\"USE2V5TMP9001\",\"2022-03-09T17:42:10Z\",38.267662048339851]]}],\"dataSources\":[{\"resourceId\":\"/subscriptions/XXXXX/resourcegroups/XXXX/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/XXXX\",\"region\":\"eastus2\",\"tables\":[\"Perf\"]}]},\"Threshold\":9,\"Operator\":\"Greater Than\",\"IncludedSearchResults\":\"True\"},\"customProperties\":null}}",
   "RequestHeader":{
      "Connection":"Keep-Alive",
      "Expect":"100-continue",
      "Host":"xxxx.webhook.eus2.azure-automation.net",
      "User-Agent":"IcMBroadcaster/1.0",
      "X-CorrelationContext":"RkkKACgAAAACAAAAEADvqM+sXFG+SYkp7Tcy2IZaAQAQAMflO8/GhoFLrHCgd8ILz2o=",
      "x-ms-request-id":"8fdd10d2-4a36-43a5-8e65-4eb20f3b9865"
   }
}
```

The above json i got it from the Azure Log Search alert and trying to customize it.

From the above json can i get the values if i refer the column section keys?.
Ex: If i mention computer then i should be able to get value USE2V5TMP9001 and AggregatedValue is 38.267662048339851.

Comment: Can someone help me to get the values from the JSON.? It's much needed for getting it, appreciate your response. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `columns` array to map the individual row values to the correct type and property name:

```
$json = @'
<json goes here>
'@

$data = $json |ConvertFrom-Json

$columnDefinitions = $data.columns

$rows = foreach($row in $data.rows){
  # prepare dictionary to hold the individual column values
  $properties = [ordered]@{}
  for($i = 0; $i -lt $row.Length; $i++){
    # extract value and column metadata
    $value  = $row[$i]
    $name = $columnDefinitions[$i].name
    $type = $columnDefinitions[$i].type

    # make sure to translate any type names if necessary
    # eg. translate `real` -> `decimal`
    if($type -eq 'real'){ $type = 'decimal' }

    # convert value to correct type and store in property dictionary
    $properties[$name] = $value -as $type
  }

  # create new object based on the row values
  [pscustomobject]$properties
}
```

`$rows` will now contain 1 or more objects with the expected values so you can now do:

```
$rows |ForEach-Object {
  # this now resolves `USE2V5TMP9001`
  $_.computer
}
```

Comment: That's the quickest comment i ever got. Let me try this first, Thank you Jessen

Comment: Hi Jessan, I tried the above script seems like the column definition & rows are not working properly. Here is the extracted details,
$data Result:

Comment: $data Result: 
name          columns                                                                                                  
----          -------                                                                                                  
PrimaryResult {@{name=Computer; type=string}, @{name=TimeGenerated; type=datetime}, @{name=AggregatedValue; type=real}}
Column Definition:
name     type  
Computer string
omputer      string  
TimeGenerated datetime
datetime
AggregatedValue real
Result:
U
1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
69
2
1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
50
12.20805296301843

Comment: @Logan The json you've posted isn't complete then - looks like it's nested inside another object `{"PrimaryResult":{...}}`. `$data = $data.PrimaryResult` right after `ConvertFrom-Json` might do the trick, but otherwise [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71422255/edit) with the correct json sample.

Comment: @Jessen, the actual post has been updated with original JSON

Comment: Any luck on the above JSON code? @Mathias R. Jessen